# Why is my HVAC system not turning on the A/C compressor?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

My AC stop cooling. Here's what I found. Inside blower is working, outside compressor/fan does not turn on. I manually push the contacts in the outside relay and the compressor and fan worked, used multi-meter in cable coming from home but no power, checked the terminals inside and no power in the terminals from the board when "call for cool".

The transformer is working fine, with 24 volts. Heater and manual fan are ok, and the interior blower turns on on AC, not the outside compressor/fan, unless done manually pushing the contacts at the relay. Also the thermostat control (digital) turns on.

I'm guessing I should have 24v when turning the AC on, so I'm thinking maybe the electronic board (Honeywell ST9160B1084) is bad. If so, I was thinking to replace it, but since is kinda old, I will need to get the universal ST9120U1011 board. Am I on the right path? Thank you.

Comment: Check the voltage at the transformer leads.

Comment: Hi Jack thank you for your answer. Yes the transformer is working fine, with 24 volts. Heater and manual fan are ok, and the interior blower turns on on AC, not the outside compressor/fan, unless done manually pushing the contacts at the relay. Also the thermostat control (digital) turns on.

Comment: Sometimes the small relays on the control board fail , but I would make sure your power supply is good first.